# Fedora 36: wmctrl does not work at all

Tags: linux, wmctrl

I have a script that I run on RHEL (currently 8.4, but this has worked on many previous versions). It uses `wmctrl -a` to activate specific windows. I just created a Fedora 36 VM on VirtualBox and there `wmctrl -a` does nothing. Likewise `wmctrl -l` lists nothing. I am using the default window manager which I believe is Gnome 41. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

`wmctrl` is a utility for `X.org`/`X11`, you are most likely running a Wayland session.

Unfortunately to the best of my knowledge Wayland doesn't have any alternatives.

Wayland developers are [not concerned](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland/-/issues/233) with anything approaching the usability of X.org.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. All I did was reconfigure not to use Wayland.

Comment: @TomLInk Please accept the answer.

Comment: @artem Sorry but it does not allow me.